Set up Build and Release pipelines to deploy a SSIS project to a SSIS in SQL Server in Azure DevOps
I have a SSIS project that sits in Azure Repos and every-time I complete and push a pull request to update main, I need it to trigger a ci/cd pipeline that will build and deploy the latest version of the SSIS project to an on premise SQL Server.
I'm currently stuck at how to start setting up the build pipeline and the yaml code. I am not familiar with PowerShell and would like to avoid using it if possible.

Does this help? https://medium.com/@bernardin.houessou/deploying-ssis-packages-with-azure-devops-for-net-projects-4b4502d9408d


I need it to trigger a ci/cd pipeline that will build and deploy the latest version of the SSIS project to an on-premises SQL Server.

Please refer the following steps:

Install the SSIS DevOps Tools extension to your organization from Azure DevOps Marketplace and refer to this page for more detailed usage and release notes.

Navigate to your project in Azure DevOps, select Pipelines, click on New pipeline button and choose your source repository.

Select the Starter pipeline template to start with an empty pipeline.

Add the SSIS Build task and SSIS Deploy task to your pipeline to your pipeline.
The following Sample YAML pipeline will be triggered when the main branch changes. To access your on-premises SQL Server, you may need to configure a Self-hosted agents to make sure the pipeline can access to the on-premises SQL Server.


trigger:
- main

pool:
  name: 'your self-hosted agent pool name'

steps:
- task: SSISBuild@1
  inputs:
    projectPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/YourSSISProjectFolder'
    configuration: 'Release'
    stripSensitive: false
    outputPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: SSISDeploy@1
  inputs:
    sourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/YourProject.ispac'
    destinationType: 'ssisdb'
    destinationServer: 'Name of destination SQL Server'
    destinationPath: 'Path of the destination folder'
    authType: 'sql'
    username: 'Username to access the SSISDB'
    password: 'Password to access the SSISDB.'
    connectionStringSuffix: 'connection string'
    whetherOverwrite: 'yes'
    whetherContinue: 'no'


Save the pipeline and it will build and deploy your SSIS project when it is triggered.

